# Animated splash-screen android in xml-format (layer-list)

Tags: android, xml, splash-screen, animationdrawable

Is it possible to make an animated splash-screen when just using a drawable xml-file (with layer-list) and call this from android Manifest file:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
```

**/style**

```
   <!-- SPLASH TEST-->
<style name="AppTheme.Launcher">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen</item>
</style>
```

**xml-file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:opacity="opaque">

<item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<item>

    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/android_splash"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</item>
```

Let say I have 5 images of android_splash (1 2 3 4 5), could I make changes in the launch-screen.xml så that the splash-screen animates? Then how would it look like in code?

cincerely

Comment: Maybe this tutorial will help you achieve it. https://medium.com/@spparks_/quick-tutorial-animated-splash-screen-f01324b724e6